# Ubuntu 18.04 screen not resizing inside Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: 18.04

Hi I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in a Oracle VM VirtualBox but my workspace is not resizing. Has anyone else ran into this issue? Thanks, Tulio

Comment: Sis you install the "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack" - this can be found on VirtualBox's website at [https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

Comment: I did change the view to scalled mode and it helped. resoution is not great but I think I can work with it.

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked on VBox - I switched to KVM quite a while ago.